# How do I use a variable in the --data section of a curl command?

Tags: shell, curl

I am writing a bash script to call curl from the command line. I sadly cannot figure out how to substitute a simple variable into the -d section of the curl request.

Why doesn't this work?

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

name=$1
test -z $name && echo "Repo name required." 1>&2 && exit 1

curl -u 'metaraine' https://api.github.com/user/repos -d '{"name":"$name"}'
```

It doesn't actually substitute the value of $name into the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this?

```
curl -u 'metaraine' https://api.github.com/user/repos -d "{\"name\":\"$name\"}"
```

That is, escape the quotes and use double quotes around the `{}` instead of simple ones.

Comment: Can you try it now? I escaped it in another way.

Comment: It worked!!! I thought for sure I had tried that. Thank you! Will need to work on my shell skills so I understand this at a deeper level.

Comment: The hint is: escape it!! :)